# Control labeling in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is there an efficient way to control the labels of tikiz circuit when labeling is uniform between 0:0.125:...:2, I want to show the number 0,0.125,..2 in the x-axis

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone} 
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{angles, arrows.meta,quotes}   
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            grid=both,
            minor tick num=17,
            grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},
            major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!50},
            axis lines=middle,
            enlargelimits={abs=0.2},
            xmin = 0, xmax = 2,
            ymin = -1, ymax = 7,
            xtick={0,0.125,0.25,0.375,0.5,0.625,0.75,0.875,1}
            xticklabels={$0$,$0.125$,$0.25$,$0.375$,$0.5$,$0.625$,$0.75$,$0.875$,$1$}
        ]
            
            \addplot[domain=0:2,samples=50,smooth,red] {4*cos(deg(2*pi*x-2*pi*0.125))+3};
   
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

- font size used in labels should be reduced
- precision of numbers had to be increased (from default) 2 to 3 decimals
- the image should be wide enough for the labels that they will not overlap

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width=15cm,
    axis lines=middle,
    grid=both,
    minor tick num=4,
    grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},
    major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!50},
    enlargelimits={abs=0.2},
    xmin = 0, xmax = 2,
    ymin = -1, ymax = 7,
    xtick={0,0.125,...,2},
    x tick label style={font=\scriptsize,
                        /pgf/number format/precision=3}
            ]
    \addplot[domain=0:2,samples=50,smooth,red] {4*cos(deg(2*pi*x-2*pi*0.125))+3};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
If it is acceptable for you to rotate `xtick` labels, for example for 45 degrees, you can then increase font size used in `xtick` labels. In this case  x tick label style is:

```
    x tick label style={font=\small, rotate=45, anchor=east,
                        /pgf/number format/precision=3,}
```

and resulted image is:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, looks wonderful